# Do you say 'decide a judgement'?

Tags: word-usage

We can make, determeine, inform, confirm, etc... a judgement.
Can we 'decide a judgement?'
I wonder if native speakers say 'decide a judgement'.

Comment: It would be redundant, because a judgment is already a decision in itself.

Comment: Weird things are said in court documents.  And lawyers are not English majors.  "Decide a judgment" might certainly be said, given that a "judgment" is a specific act by a judge.

Answer (score 2):

The ngram viewer reports no results for *decide a judgment*.  The reason may be that a judgment is a decision, so the locution has the slightly awkward form of *decide a decision*.  The google reports 183K hits, many of which are false drops.  The number seems high considering that there are only three pages of results. By way of contrast *make a judgment* and *form a judgment* get about 2M hits.  There is this sentence from a *New York Times* article ["The Woman Who Beat the Klan"](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/11/01/magazine/the-woman-who-beat-the-klan.html?pagewanted=all)

> "I do hope you **decide a judgment** against me and everyone else involved."

Here the word *judgment* means an award of monetary damages in a civil suit, which is somewhat different from the ordinary meaning of an opinion or decision. The speaker was a plaintiff in the case; his lawyer would have used the legal term of art *recover a judgment*.

The ngram viewer reports the following [verbs](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB%20a%20judgment&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bform_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bforming_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmake_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbe_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bobtained_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpass_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpronounce_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brecovered_VERB%20a%20judgment%3B%2Cc0) (in order of decreasing popularity) that license *a judgment* as a direct object:

- make
- form
- obtain
- pronounce
- pass
- recover

The last four find use in the US legal system.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So is it proper to say that native speakers do not normally say 'decide a judgement'?

Comment: It's grammatical, it makes sense, and it occasionally turns up in print, but I think it's safe to say that native speakers by far prefer other verbs.

Comment: I don't think the post is referring to that sense, in any case.